# is there a technical difference between Mamp and Mamp Pro?

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I've got an issue with my website which I can't find a solution to - it's loading extremely slow on some devices (sofar tested on 2 iMac and iPhone 6 and SE).

I wanted to exclude the possibility of the web host causing this problem, so I migrated the site to a local environment - using MAMP.

Now, a whole new issue comes up.

On MAMP (free) it loads exactly as on a live server - over a minute loading time.

However, on MAMP Pro it loads instantaneously - as it should.

So I am wondering, if there's some backend difference between these to ?

I don't understand why there should be, but I also can't explain why this happens.

I was planning to use Mamp free long-term, so this is a bit worrying.

Thanks!